# Multiple Person sms at the sametime in ios?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I have a requirement where I need to send SMS messages to multiple people at the same time.  I'm not aware any third party APIs for this.  Do you have any suggestions to accomplish this?

Comment: If you're asking about sending SMS messages without the user's knowledge: no.

Comment: it is possible to hide the sent history in my iphone

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you're based, [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-sms) is a good option.  They have extensive documentation and good example code.

Comment: Am very new to iphone appliction am not understanding that could to paste any sample code here then i will follow that one

Comment: It is a REST API using XML Post data.  Try some code and find out what specific questions you have, then post those here.